# Проблема с JS/jQuery и Brackets

Tags: javascript, jquery

Вот такая проблема JS/jQuery 
[image: Проблема с JS/jQuery кодом]

Так же выдает ошибку в скачанном jQuery
[image: Скачанный jQuery]

Comment: а если так... `jQuery(ducument).ready(function(){ // код});`

Answer (score 0):

Вот посмотрите в сниппете, работает

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function() {
    $("body").append("<a href='http://google.kz'>Скачать в google</a>");
  });
</script>
```